# Getting cannot invoke "java.sql.connect.createStatement()" because "connectDB" is null

Tags: java

Here's the code I'm using along with with log, I'm not sure why this is happening since I'm pretty new to using databases.
I've provided both the login validation and the getConnection() method, since I'm sure where I've gone wrong. All help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
public void validateLogin(){
        DatabaseConnection connectNow = new DatabaseConnection();
        Connection connectDB = connectNow.getConnection();

        String verifyLogin = "SELECT count(1) FROM user_account WHERE username = '" + usernameTextField.getText() + "' AND password ='" + passwordEnterField.getText() + "'";

        try{
            Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
            ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery(verifyLogin);

            while (queryResult.next()){
                if (queryResult.getInt(1) == 1){
                    loginMessage.setText("Login Successful");
                }else {
                    loginMessage.setText("Invalid Login, try again");
                }
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.getCause();
        }
    }
```

getConnection() method:

```
public Connection getConnection(){
        String databaseName = "accounts";
        String databaseUser = "username";
        String databasePassword = "password";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + databaseName;

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            databaseLink = DriverManager.getConnection(url,databaseUser,databasePassword);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
            e.getCause();
        }
        return databaseLink;
    }
```

Logs:
*java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.createStatement()" because "connectDB" is null
at Zimsy/demonic.LoginController.validateLogin(LoginController.java:67)
at Zimsy/demonic.LoginController.loginButtonAction(LoginController.java:49)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)*

Comment: Well `connectDB` is null, so you need to look at the `getConnection()` method to work out why that's returning null.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure if there's anything wrong with the getConnection() method but I'll add it here so please tell me if there's something wrong that I am doing.

Comment: Please edit this into your question - you can format it better there.

Comment: @Hulk okay, I'll do that

Comment: Yes, there's something *very* wrong with your `getConnection()` method. If anything goes wrong, you catch the exception, do nothing with it (you fetch the stack trace and cause but don't *do* anything with them) and then carry on as if nothing is wrong. I strongly suspect an exception is being thrown. Catching exceptions like that and ignoring them is almost *always* a bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh okay, any suggestions on what i should do.

Comment: You need to out why `getConnection` is failing.  Look at the stacktrace that is produced by that method.  Then do some research on the cause.  (Possible causes include a missing driver JAR, using the wrong class name for the driver, incorrect connection parameters, database not reachable and so on.  The stacktrace will immediately eliminate some of those as possibilities.)

Comment: @StephenC Alright, thank you.